# Grabbing data from output

Tags: php

I have an object I'm trying to get data from. But I seem to be stuck, any help would be great, Thanks.

```
function att($prop, $what){
$reflObj = new ReflectionObject($prop);
$get = $reflObj->getProperty('attributes');
$get->setAccessible(true);
$info = $get->getValue($prop);

foreach($info as $inf){
$reflObj = new ReflectionObject($inf);

$title = $reflObj->getProperty('name');
$title->setAccessible(true);
$description = $title->getValue($inf);

var_dump("$description");

}
}
```

Example of output so far:

```
string(11) "< Min Child"
string(9) "< Train S"
string(4) "<Pub"
string(5) "<Shop"
string(7) "Balcony"
string(4) "Bath"
string(9) "Bathrooms"
string(3) "BBQ"
string(5) "Beach"
string(9) "Bed Linen"
string(8) "Internet"
string(15) "Central Heating"
string(7) "Coast <"
string(3) "Cot"
```

Basically looking to grab the data from each.

Comment: DO you want to the data all at once?

Comment: No just to be able to pick and choose bits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($info as $inf){
$reflObj = new ReflectionObject($inf);

$title = $reflObj->getProperty('name');
$title->setAccessible(true);
$description = $title->getValue($inf);

var_dump("$description");

}
```

Change this line into this:

```
$everything = array();
foreach($info as $inf){
    $reflObj = new ReflectionObject($inf);

    $title = $reflObj->getProperty('name');
    $title->setAccessible(true);
    $description = $title->getValue($inf);

    $everything[] = $description;

}
var_dump($everything);
```

`$everything` is now an array that holds data ordered by that output. Access its values like this:

`$everything[0]`

Replace 0 with index of what you need. For instance, `3` will yield to 4th member which is `"<Shop"`.

You can print them with `echo`:

`echo $everything[0];`

Reminder: `var_dump()` is a debug tool for outputting object data. It should never be used to grab input since its implementation may vary among systems. All `var_dump()` code should be omitted from the released application unless it is particularly necessary.

Comment: Awesome, I'm getting a nice output now.

array(83) { [0]=> string(11) "< Min Child" [1]=> string(9) "< Train S" [2]=> string(4) " string(5) " string(7) "Balcony" [5]=> string(4) "Bath" [6]=> string(9) "Bathrooms" [7]=>

How would I push out the relevant data from each then?

Comment: What is the identifier that seperates those values from each other?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: Do you mean `$reflObj->getProperty('name')` with every possible call that is valid?

Comment: Editted my answer in case what you need is array access.

Comment: I'm looking to do a if statement to pull out whatever I wish, such as "Internet" and then return the value.

Comment: Use `array_search()`. Here is the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Comment: I have got the search working, how would I pull out the data from it?

Comment: What do you mean by pulling out?

Comment: I'm not great with arrays, I seem to be pulling a int(10) if I var_dump. I'm not sure if this is the correct data. Below is the original object:

object(tabs\api\core\Attribute)#87 (2) {
      ["name":protected]=>
      string(8) "Internet"
      ["value":protected]=>
      bool(true)

Comment: Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Would really appreciate a few more minutes of your time.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37016/discussion-between-diegoperini-and-alex)